# precision and recall in lucene

Tags: lucene

hello all
I was wondering, if I want to measure precision and recall in lucene then what's the best way for me to do it? is there any sample cource code that I can use?

a little background, I am using lucene to create a kind of search engine for my thesis. and I also wanted to do an analysis of how well those search engine performs and the only way to do that I think is for me to compute the precision and recall metrics. so any suggestion would be helpful.

thanks though

Comment: You question is far too vague. If you want people to put effort into an answer, then you need to put some effort into your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [these](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/IfMhiQKNJ8usHwjHcWbi) [email threads](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Precision-recall-curve-with-contrib-benchmark-quality-td844442.html). Alternatively, you can use [MRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank).
See also [Search Application Relevance Issues](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Search-Application-Relevance-Issues).